# react-chartjs error Cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have installed react-chartjs. When following the instructions to test it I get an error cannot read property 'Chart' of undefined' at line 10 Chart.js

here is my code

```
var React = require('react');
var Chart = require('chart.js');
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;


var LineChart = React.createClass({


  render: function() {

    return <LineChart width="600" height="250"/>
  }
});
```

module.exports = LineChart;

Im stumped and cannot find any solutions online.  Thanks for any comments

Comment: What are you using to bundle everything? Webpack?

Comment: Thanks for your comment , yes webpack is the tool I am using.

Comment: I'm using an old version of React.js v0.13 . Maybe that is the issue

Comment: I've also used react-chart-commonjs , just because it says on npm its easier to use with webpack ( no idea why ?) and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are there any peer dependencies to that package? Try `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean`, and then `npm i` and see if it complains about any peer deps

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm encountering the same error.

Comment: Someone suggested Did you specifically run "npm install chart.js" in your terminal when you installed react-chartjs?  , but I moved on to use D3 I didnt resolve this problem due to time constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `LineChart` twice. Change the name of one of them, for example:

```
var MyChart = React.createClass({ /* rest of your code */ });
module.exports = MyChart;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Renaming  didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, and 'npm cache clean' helps!
It may related to the dependency of chartjs & react-chartjs.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Exclusion of node_modules in Webpack build helped. Look at this https://github.com/jhudson8/react-chartjs/issues/93.

Here's an example "module" section of `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```